# uninstall Ubuntu 15.10 and replace it with 14.04?

Tags: uninstall, 15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 on a laptop that I want to remove and replace it by 14.04 release. I've already made a bootable flash with 14.04 OS. I tried just to plug it and reboot but nothing happened .. Any one can help me in this ??? Thannks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Ubuntu installation media was not created properly.

Open the **Disks** tool in Ubuntu and create the install media.

Select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.

Choose the installation ISO file and the USB drive to write it to.

Start restoring - when finished reboot and select the USB drive.

In case you can't choose it manually, change boot order in BIOS.

Comment: sorry but this version has no graphics at all :(

Comment: @KhalilA : Please explain ... what do you mean with : This version has no graphics at all ? You said that you have Ubuntu 15.10 on your laptop ... so create the Ubuntu 14.04 installation media by using the disks tool from there ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in the BIOS, what booted first? Normally it is the OS (so for you Ubuntu 15.10).

You need to change the boot order to your USB.

Here find some information:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Just check the point:

1. BIOS is not set to boot from CD or DVD drive
2. PC requires you to hold down or press a key to boot from CD

For the boot order of course do not put DVD/cd but USB key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I checked BIOS and removable devices are set first but still it starts from hard drive it seems straight on

Comment: Ok, how did you create your USB?